# The specified structure must be blittable or have layout information

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to serialize a structure into a byte array and send it to my client which is written in C++. Unfortunately, I am getting the error `The specified structure must be blittable or have layout information`

```
Int32 structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
byte[] structBytes = new byte[structSize];
GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(structBytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pStructBytes = gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();
Marshal.StructureToPtr(this, pStructBytes, false);
gch.Free();
```

I have tried changing the structure a couple of times to fix error. Note that I also want to make sure that even if the string members are set to something during struct creation that is only say, 100 bytes, the remaining 155 will be there 0's to ensure the total length is correct (510). Here are two of my attempts:

```
StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 1)]
public struct RenameObject
{
    [field: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 255)]
    public string path;
    [field: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 255)]
    public string newpath;
};
```

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 1)]
public struct RenameObject
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    string path;
    [FieldOffset(255)]
    string newpath;
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The specified structure must be blittable or have layout information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439983/error-the-specified-structure-must-be-blittable-or-have-layout-information)

Comment: No, it does not